# Does using htmlspecialchar(), mysql_real_escape_string, trim() and str_replace enough?

Tags: php

Is usage of `htmlspecialchar`, `mysql_real_escape_string` and `str_replace` enough for protection from SQL injections and XSS-based attacks?

I'm writing a software for a forum site. So for that I want to protect my site. I am not good at making PDO statements and want to use the above library functions.

By using `htmlspecialchar` single and double quotes, greater than, less than and ampersand signs will become encoded and will prevent XSS attacks. And I will not decode those to their original form.

Then, `mysql_real_escape_string` will prevent the first order of SQL injections.

Third, `trim` will remove white spaces from both ends.(this may be optional)

Finally, if I use `str_replace` to replace all table names and database names entered through codes to other names will it be safe?

Example:
Suppose I have a database name `ABC` and table name `XYZ`.
Now someone uses this statement:

```
statement = "SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE name = '" + userName + "';"

                          OR
SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE name = '' OR '1'='1' -- ';

                          OR

a';DROP TABLE XYZ; SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE 't' = 't
```

Here, if I replace table name `XYZ` To `DEF` using `str_replace` then I think the code will have no effect since there is no such table name.

SQL injections like

```
1 OR 1=1, I Will Also str_replace \1\.
```

I will have only `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `SELECT` And `DELETE` privilege for database and all these words will also be `str_replace` by me.

[ Please forgive me for my wrong english. ]

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Probably a beginner...

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Perhaps.  But the more pressing point is that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, so they should be avoided.

Comment: cAn YoU PlEaSe StOp uSiNg CaPiTaL cHaRacTeRs In ThE mIdDlE oF sEnTeNcE???

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Instead of just mentioning PDO I would urge the OP to look up prepared statements and bind parameters.

Comment: @tirthankar - Please do not start writing any kind of script yourself, at least not with your current knowledges. As somebody else pointed out, use an existing framework that will do the hard work for you. From my understanding, you are confusing things and don't have a clue what various vulnerabilities really mean which in the end will lead to your system being hacked. Don't think that if you wrap your vars like: `$a = a(b(c(d($_POST['x']))));` you are safe because `you use` the functions. Just make the time and read about xss and sql injections, etc...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It was discussed on meta, that we shouldn't comment on that anymore, that shows he is a beginner and he is referring some old tutorial

Comment: @Mr.Alien: We shouldn't comment on that?  Why not?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143379/automatically-warn-against-the-use-of-mysql-functions-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @Mr.Alien: But this is different.  The OP is essentially asking for advice on best practice, and knows of the existence of PDO.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth He is indian, and I know our mentality, you will tll him to learn pdo, he won't give a damn about our advice, actually this question is not suited for SO

Comment: @OliCharlesworth inested to use PDO, could I use mysqli too? is almost the same right?

Answer (score 4):

No. It's never enough. XSS can happen in attribute, without any < or > signs.

Also you will be vulnerable to header injections (if you are sending e-mail for example)

and replacing the table names is just plain wrong.

Escape all data send to database and make sure when you are expecting numbers, and not string, you are passing numbers (cast to number).

Escape all output. But if you are using dynamic data in attributes, better use HTMLPurifier to clear your HTML.

If you have file uploads, secure them. Make sure the user can't upload executable file and can't override a file. Don't trust the $_FILES['name'] property

If you are sending e-mail, be aware of header injections.

And best of all, just use a proven framework. It can provide the PDO functionality and escaping for you.